# Simple leak not showing in Instruments-Leak tool

Tags: objective-c

Why when the following code (intentionally leaky) is executed with the Instrument-Leaks tool, does it show that there is a leak for NSObject, but not NSDate?  They both show up when run with the Analyze static analysis tool as I would expect.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSObject* obj = [NSObject alloc];
    obj = [NSObject alloc];

    NSDate* date = [NSDate alloc];
    date = [NSDate alloc];

    sleep(10); // time to allow leaks to pick up sample
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've experienced the same thing before. I've also tried intentionally leaking stuff and Instruments did not detect them. I guess Instruments does not check as thorough as you would expect.

Comment: I would suggest you look into the WWDC 2010 videos. Session 311 covered this topic pretty good.

Comment: FYI - With Instruments you can adjust how often it polls for leaks, and reduce the time from 10 seconds. I believe the setting is called `secs Between Auto Detections` and is in the left hand panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a assumption: NSDate could implement some pretty-hard hacks for performance which makes its -alloc method return a cached value.

Comment: No, that would be totally against their own memory philosophy.

Comment: This certainly seems possible.  One way to test is to add `initWith...` messages to each instance so that it produces different dates, and see if it then leaks.  Objective-C initializers are allowed to return a different instance so NSDate may simply be returning a dummy object from alloc.

Comment: I tried the above and it showed up leaking __NSCFDate - thanks